# Can a custom component call PopUpManager.addPopUp on itself? How does one put the pop-up logic inside the component?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to organise my code better and figured it would be good to place the pop-up logic within the component that's being popped-up. However, I can't seem to do this without causing one error or another. I also need to make the pop-up modal.

I'm doing something along these lines (psuedo code):

```
<mx:TitleWindow >
    <mx:Label id="messageLabel" />
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

    public function show():void{
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(this, Application.application as DisplayObject, true);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
    }
    public function hide():void{
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
    }

]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: That code looks fine to me, thats how you use the PopUpManager class.  If you are having a specific error post it, otherwise nobody can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this works, after all.

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but after Ryan's response I rewrote the code, using the above pseudo code as a starting point. Now it seems to work.